# Cannot use new version of android to compile my app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio with Xamarin, as shown in the picture, the latest available android version for me is JellyBean, this is preventing me from using quite some new features. I have set the target version to 6.0 and minimum required version to 4.0.3. [Current Configuration in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMeBS.png)

Does anyone has experience how to solve this issue? 
Many thanks!
Greeting,
Kyle
[the screenshot at version selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukHE5.png)

Comment: Do you at least have that version in your Android SDK: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the current referenced `Mono.Android.dll` in your project. You are most likely setting your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to only Jellybean here. That or the highest level of Android you have installed is Jellybean and it's using the latest platform available via the following in your `.csproj`:

`<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>`

EX:

If you set your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` in your `.csproj` to Jellybean:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.3</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Or via the GUI in Properties -> Application -> Compile using Android version:

Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean)

You would then only have a reference to the 4.3 version of `Mono.Android.dll` which only includes `Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes` enums up to Jellybean.

Thus if you had changed your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `v6.0` you would have access to all the current `Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes` enums up to Marshmallow. You may need to ensure that you have these API levels installed in your Android SDK, and that the respective `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` is the correct version of the respective API version you'd like to use in the enum.

Comment: Dear Jon, thank you for your reply. That's the thing that bothers me that much, because the target version and TargetFrameworkVersion is set to latest in my project. but don't know if any other things can cause that. Even if i set the targetFrameworkVersion to 2.3 it still doesn't change anything.